# Show output before Read-Host

Tags: powershell

I'm having some issues getting some info to write to the console before Read-Host.  Let me throw out a simplified example.

```
Function Add-Build {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)][String]$Build
      ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)][System.Nullable``1[[System.Int32]]]$VersionID
      ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=3)][String]$BuildDescription
)

    Write-Host -BackgroundColor DarkYellow "Adding SQL Build $($Build)"


IF ($VersionID -eq $null)
{
    Get-SqlVersions | Out-String


    $VersionID = Read-Host -Prompt "SELECT Version (Enter To Skip)" | % { IF ($_ -eq '') {$null} ELSE {$_}}
    }
}

FUNCTION Test-Function {

   $BuildID = (Get-BuildID -Build "11.0.3156.0").ToString()
}
```

If I call `Add-Build` directly then the `Get-SqlVersions | Out-String` output before the `Read-Host.`  If I call `Test-Function` though the `Get-SqlVersions` no longer outputs to the console at all.  `Get-SqlVersions` makes a SQL proc call and the output is a couple Datarows.

Is there a way to ensure the `Get-SqlVersions` data shows up when calling `Test-Function`?

Comment: Make it output to the host. `$GetSQL = Get-SqlVersions | Out-String; Write-Host $GetSQL`

Comment: Worked perfectly, put that up as the answer and I'll gladly accept.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it explicitly output to the host.

```
$GetSQL = Get-SqlVersions | Out-String
Write-Host $GetSQL
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I stumbled on it and can't help but contribute.

The problem is here:

Get-SqlVersions | Out-String

Change it to this:

Get-SqlVersions | Out-Host

I did some quick looking around, and Out-String seems to collect and prepare things for displaying. Out-Host just does it.

Comment: After some measuring I've found out that Out-Host performs way slower then Out-String. No surprise on that, but here are the stats: 
For a 10k array, Out-String outputs it on average in 114 ms. 
Out-Host outputs it on average in 833 ms. 

For completeness, Out-Null outputs it on avg in 14 ms. Avg based on 20 samples

Answer (score 0):

Could you please store `Get-SqlVersions | Out-String;` in a Variable and display that. I think that should work.

```
$versions = Get-SqlVersions | Out-String; 
$versions
```

Comment: That actually outputs to `Write-Output`, which when called from his second function would be consumed by the variable.

Comment: Use Write-host Followed by the variable then..:)