# Powershell Script Works Correctly in Alteryx Designer but not on Alteryx Gallery

Tags: powershell, alteryx

I asked this over on the Alteryx forums and unfortunately didn't get any answer. Hopefully someone here with Alteryx/PS experience will know the issue. I have a workflow that runs a batch file with a tabcmd command to export data from tableau into a csv in a share drive folder. Then a powershell script runs that reorders the columns, and moves them to another folder. Finally, a second powershell script runs, converts the csv to xlsx and exports that to another folder. When I run it locally in Alteryx Designer, it works just fine and I get the expected output. When I run it in Alteryx Gallery, the workflow completes with no errors but it doesn't give me the expected out. It goes through the tabcmd step and the first powershell script with the correct output, but does not perform the second powershell script correctly. Please see below for script, the --- are there to omit sensitive information.

```
$SharedDriveFolderPath = "\\---\shares\Groups\---\---\---\---\--\B\"
$files = Get-ChildItem $SharedDriveFolderPath -Filter *.csv
 foreach ($f in $files){
$outfilename = $f.BaseName +'.xlsx'
$outfilename
#Define locations and delimiter
$csv = "\\---\shares\Groups\---\---\---\---\--\B\$f" #Location of the source file
$xlsx = "\\---\shares\Groups\---\---\---\---\---\---\C\$outfilename" #Desired location of output
$delimiter = "," #Specify the delimiter used in the file

# Create a new Excel workbook with one empty sheet
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

# Build the QueryTables.Add command and reformat the data
$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $csv)
$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
$query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)
$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $delimiter
$query.TextFileParseType  = 1
$query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,1 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
$query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

# Execute & delete the import query
$query.Refresh()
$query.Delete()

# Save & close the Workbook as XLSX.
$Workbook.SaveAs($xlsx,51)
$excel.Quit()
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything of Alteryx but I see a potential PowerShell gotcha where you probably try to reveal `$outfilename` but actually put it on the pipeline (which ***might*** eventually display it *but* could also be picked up by a cmdlet as the first -sample- object and mesh up the rest of the input), see also [PowerShell function works fine when on its own, but stops working when followed by another function. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65953267/1701026). In other words: try `Write-Host $outfilename` instead.

Comment: Tried both removing line 5 and replacing with your suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't change the issue. I appreciate your suggestion, though.